# findOneAndUpdate Not Updating Discriminator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a REST API using Node, Express and Mongoose. Everything works perfectly when I update the base model. But when I try to update the discriminator object `sportEvent` in this case, it doesn't work.

**Event.js** - Event data model has a base schema common for all the collections with a discriminator for additional detail for that collection.

```js
// base schema for all the events
// includes basic detail for all the events
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  //title for the event
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  //description for the events 
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  //event type for the event. such as Music, Sports, Expo, Leisure
  eventType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
}, { discriminatorKey: 'eventType' });

//sport event model for extending the basic event model
const sportEvent = Event.discriminator("sports", new Schema({
  sportEvent: {
    //sport name. for eg: cricket, football, etc
    sportName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    //first team name
    firstTeam: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    //second team name
    secondTeam: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  }
}));
```

**EventController.js** - has a PUT method for updating the collection. Here is a code snippet.

```js
//for updating the event added a PUT method in /event route
router.put('/events/:eventId', function(req, res, next){
  //getting the event id form the url
  eventId = req.params.eventId;

  //checking the provided event id is a valid mongodb _id object or not
  if(objectId.isValid(eventId)){
    Event.findOneAndUpdate({_id: eventId}, {$set: req.body}, {new: true, runValidators: true}, function(err, event){
      if(err) {
        next(err);
      }
      sendResponse(res, "Event Successfully Updated", event);
    });
  } else {
    //sending a bad request error to the user if the event id is not valid
    sendError(res, 400, "Invalid Event ID");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure the discriminator key is present in the update object, or as an argument to the update function, write a switch case based on discriminator key, call update on the specific Schema type

```
callback = function(err, doc){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log(doc)
};

var id = ObjectId("5a75d22e6dabf3102c059f56");

var update = {
    title : 'title-name',
    eventType : 'sports' ,
    sportEvent : {
        firstTeam : 'first-name',
        secondTeam : 'second-name',
        sportName : 'sport-name'
    }
};

switch(update.eventType){
    case 'sports':
        SportEventSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set : update}, {new : true, upsert : false}, callback)
        break;
    case 'games':
        GameEventSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set : update}, {new : true, upsert : false}, callback)
        break;
    default:
        Event.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set : update}, {new : true, upsert : false}, callback);
        break;
}
```

output : update for a **sports** event type

```
Mongoose: events.findAndModify({ eventType: 'sports', _id: ObjectId("5a75d22e6dabf3102c059f56") }, [], { '$set': { title: 'title-name', eventType: 'sports', sportEvent: { firstTeam: 'first-name', secondTeam: 'second-name', sportName: 'sport-name' } } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{ sportEvent:
   { firstTeam: 'first-name',
     secondTeam: 'second-name',
     sportName: 'sport-name' },
  eventType: 'sports',
  _id: 5a75d22e6dabf3102c059f56,
  title: 'title-name',
  description: 'desc',
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: Its intended to be like this. But I wanted to update it from the base schema for obvious reason. Its a workaround. I recently saw a feature request on mongoose's GitHub for a similar kind of feature. Hope they implement it. I will mark is as my answer.

Comment: @YogendraRawal Hi, do you have the issue id for this feature request on Mongoose? thx.

Comment: If anyone is looking for the issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6087

Comment: @HishamMubarak Sure!

Answer (score 0):

As of Mongoose 6, you can modify the value of the discriminator key by using the [`overwriteDiscriminatorKey`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html#updating-the-discriminator-key) option:

```js
//for updating the event added a PUT method in /event route
router.put('/events/:eventId', function (req, res, next) {
  //getting the event id form the url
  eventId = req.params.eventId;

  //checking the provided event id is a valid mongodb _id object or not
  if (objectId.isValid(eventId)) {
    Event.findById(eventId, function (err, event) {
      Event.replaceOne(
        { _id: eventId },
        { ...event.toObject(), ...req.body },
        {
          overwriteDiscriminatorKey: true,
          new: true,
          runValidators: true,
        },
        function (err, event) {
          if (err) {
            next(err);
          }
          sendResponse(res, 'Event Successfully Updated', event);
        }
      );
    });
    
  } else {
    //sending a bad request error to the user if the event id is not valid
    sendError(res, 400, 'Invalid Event ID');
  }
});
```